# Question about l' and gl'

Tags: grammar, articles, apocope

In ["Vissi d'arte" from Tosca](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RStRJ7ccm4Q&t=1m21s), she says the following:

> Sempre con fè sincera
>      diedi fiori agl'altar
>      ...
>      Diedi gioielli della Madonna al manto
>      e diedi il canto agli astri, al ciel
>      che ne ridean più belli

Assuming *altar* is an apocope of *altare*, why *agl'altar* here?

One thought I had was that maybe it was plural:

> a gli altari = agli altari = agl'altari = agl'altar

But I couldn't find a single translation that translates it as plural ("altars"). I'm also not sure if this is how Italian works (she also says *agli astri* without any contraction later).

**My question:**  Are *agl'altar* and *all'altar(e)* synonyms? If so, is there a reason to chose one over the other?

Comment: It's not quite 100% perfect Italian, as you noticed yourself (the correct form would be *agli altari*). It is understandable to a native speaker though and I assume it was chosen for reasons of meter. It might be worth saying that to my ears what Mirella Freni says is much more similar to *all'altar*, in the singular form. It's not like *agl'altar* and *all'altar* are very different in pronunciation...

Comment: I think it should be "agli altar": http://opera.stanford.edu//Puccini/Tosca/act2.html (but I've not listened to Mirella Freni in the video).

Comment: @Charo I'm an idiot. I didn't think of looking at the libretto for the actual opera  All of those translations are wrong, then. Take a look [here](http://www.murashev.com/opera/Tosca_libretto_Italian_English), it's translated as "I brought flowers to the altars". My world has been shaken a little bit.

Comment: I saw some mentions online of stuff like `agl'Altar` so I was starting to assume `agl'` was like an "elevated" form of `all'` or something (like `i dei` and `gli Dei`). I shouldn't've been so quick to dismiss the possibility of it being plural.

Comment: "Gli" is a plural article ("agli" = "a" + "gli"), so I think the translation "to the altars" is correct. As explained by @DenisNardin, "altari" is truncated to "altar" for meter reasons.

Comment: In modern standard Italian *“i dei” is not grammatical...

Comment: Here you can find an explanation of what @DaG is saying: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/D/dei-gli-dei.shtml.

Answer (score 2):

In order to comply with the meter, the *librettista* had to do a couple of adjustments:

1. make the hiatus *agli altari* into a diphthong, so *agli altari* → *agl’altari* (not used in standard language, it's a poetry trick);
2. truncate the final word, so *altari* → *altar*

It is possible that some editions of the libretto have *agli altar*, because a singer will know that keeping the meter needs a diphthong there. For instance, http://opera.stanford.edu//Puccini/Tosca/act2.html has *agli altar*; however it also has *fe’*, which is wrong and should be *fé*. The spelling *fè* is probably in the original, because at that time the acute accent was not used.

Answer (score 0):

> Are agl'altar and all'altar(e) synonyms? If so, is there a reason to
>   chose one over the other?

The only difference is that the first is plural and the second is singular.

a + gli : a + plural article

a + lo : a + singular article